# How to start gunicorn automatically in server with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, gunicorn

client name is siar, unroot here is my idea:

1. `sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/systemd/system`
2. `sudo vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/siar.service`

and it's context：

```
[Unit]
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
[Service]
User=siar
WorkingDirectory=/home/siar/sites/django-blog-learning/blogproject
ExecStart=/home/siar/sites/env/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/siar.socket blogproject.wsgi:application
Restart=on-failure
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3. `sudo systemctl start siar`

and here I get error:

```
Failed to start siar.service: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
See system logs and 'systemctl status siar.service' for details.
```

#### After `cat /var/log/syslog`

And i find the error :

```
Dec  4 23:43:33 iZwz92ma406e6d08vhkwqmZ dbus[305]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' (using servicehelper)
Dec  4 23:43:33 iZwz92ma406e6d08vhkwqmZ dbus[305]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
```

#### I had tried

`systemctl status siar.service`
And the result is
`Failed to get properties: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1`
I don't know what it 's meaning

#### and give the folder peimissions:

```
chmod 777 /usr/lib/systemd/system
```

Nothing happen

#### Seemingly,i try other .service and there are the same errors

Now,i can use `start` to achieve gunicorn working automatically,but the command, `systemctl` still failed to start siar.service

Comment: Did you follow the advice to "See system logs" and the status command for details?

Comment: Check log and status and post here, please.

Comment: Please copy-paste the result of running systemctl status siar.service after running your script. The non-UTF8 chars in your conf might be killing the service start script.

Comment: i had tried `systemctl status siar.service` and the result is `Failed to get properties: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1`

Comment: The systemctl startup script for the service you are trying to start is dying miserably. Try to start it without your config and if it fires up, you know you have a bad config. To do that, cleanup the service (either purge it and reinstall or use default -if provided- config).

Comment: Do you have the appropriate permissions set on the folder in your .service file?